# How to use canvas to draw a picture

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am new in Android currently learning canvas and I want to create below type of picture.
I searched for it but can not get proper Example.

[image]

Can anyone help me? How can I create it?

Comment: what do you have so far? code and output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this **code** first :

```
public class CustomView extends View {

    public static final int NO_OF_VERTICAL_CIRCLES = 5;
    public static final int NO_OF_HORIZONTAL_CIRCLES = 4;

    public static final float RADIUS = 60f;

    private Paint mPaintImage;

    private RectF[] rectangles = new RectF[NO_OF_HORIZONTAL_CIRCLES
            * NO_OF_VERTICAL_CIRCLES];

    // Just creating a view for drawing
    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        // This is paint for your drawing
        mPaintImage = new Paint();

        mPaintImage.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaintImage.setFilterBitmap(true);
        mPaintImage.setDither(true);
        // color for circle
        mPaintImage.setColor(Color.RED);
        // fill style
        mPaintImage.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {

        // Account for padding
        float xpad = (float) (getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight());
        float ypad = (float) (getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom());
        // getting area for drawing you can also get it using getWidth() and getHeight()
        float ww = (float) w - xpad;
        float hh = (float) h - ypad;

        Creating Rectangle for drawing your circles
        for (short i = 0; i < NO_OF_HORIZONTAL_CIRCLES; i++) {
            for (short j = 0; j < NO_OF_VERTICAL_CIRCLES; j++) {
                // calculating horizontal centers
                float horizontalCenter = RADIUS + i * (ww - RADIUS * 2)
                        / (NO_OF_HORIZONTAL_CIRCLES - 1);
                // calculating vertical centers
                float verticalCenter = RADIUS + j * (hh - RADIUS * 2)
                        / (NO_OF_VERTICAL_CIRCLES - 1);

                rectangles[j + NO_OF_VERTICAL_CIRCLES * i] = new RectF(
                        horizontalCenter - RADIUS, verticalCenter - RADIUS,
                        horizontalCenter + RADIUS, verticalCenter + RADIUS);

            }
        }

        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // Here drawing circles
        for (RectF rect : rectangles) {
            canvas.drawCircle(rect.centerX(), rect.centerY(), RADIUS,
                    mPaintImage);
        }
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
```

Here what i did is just divide sreen in grids and then find out centers and draw circle accordingly.

In similar way you can draw bitmaps, rectangles.

You can also draw on empty bitmaps.

I hope this will help.

PS (Screen shot) ::

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since you are new to Android and learning canvas here is a simple class code extending a view - you can override canvas onDraw to draw on canvas

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class MyView extends View {

    private Paint p;

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet aSet) {

                    super(context, aSet);

                  //it's best not to create any new objects in the onDraw

                    //initialize as class variables

                    p = new Paint();

    }


       @Override

       public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

            //paint specs

           p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
           p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
           p.setDither(true);
           p.setAntiAlias(true);
           p.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
           p.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

           // space between dots

           int delta = 50;

           // dot radius

           int r = 10;

           // 1st row

           canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth()/4, canvas.getHeight()/4, r, p);
           canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth()/4+delta, canvas.getHeight()/4, r, p);
           canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth()/4+delta*2, canvas.getHeight()/4, r, p);
           canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth()/4+delta*3, canvas.getHeight()/4, r, p);

           // 2nd row

           canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth()/4, canvas.getHeight()/4+delta, r, p);
           canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth()/4+delta, canvas.getHeight()/4+delta, r, p);
           canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth()/4+delta*2, canvas.getHeight()/4+delta, r, p);
           canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth()/4+delta*3, canvas.getHeight()/4+delta, r, p);

           // 3rd row

           canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth()/4, canvas.getHeight()/4+delta*2, r, p);
           canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth()/4+delta, canvas.getHeight()/4+delta*2, r, p);
           canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth()/4+delta*2, canvas.getHeight()/4+delta*2, r, p);
           canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth()/4+delta*3, canvas.getHeight()/4+delta*2, r, p);


           // 4th row

           canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth()/4, canvas.getHeight()/4+delta*3, r, p);
           canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth()/4+delta, canvas.getHeight()/4+delta*3, r, p);
           canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth()/4+delta*2, canvas.getHeight()/4+delta*3, r, p);
           canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth()/4+delta*3, canvas.getHeight()/4+delta*3, r, p);

       }


}
```